# HitTest in Adobe Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Is there any way to get the top most UI element in a specific x,y location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var objects:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(x, y));
```

Where `objects[0]` will be the top most object. (I think)

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint()

Comment: Very nice.  Also, be wary of this function if you have a lot of objects on the screen & are repeating it like in a mouseMove handler since it's not the fastest function there is.

Comment: Also note that the x,y values are relative to the stage so you may have to use obj.localToGlobal(point) to translate them.

Comment: and it is not objects[0], but objects[objects.length-1] that is the top ui element :) I happen to have needed it aswell a few days ago :p